# C++ comparing variables as an object

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compare two variables and the type of these variables are "Time". I can't seem to use the == / != function for these.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Stock.h"

using namespace std;

void Stock::setShares(int d, int m, int y, int h, int mts, double p, int vol, double val)
{
   date.setDate(d, m, y);
   time.setTime(h, mts);
   price = p;
   value = val;
   volume = vol;
}

Date Stock::getDate() const
{
  return date;
}

Time Stock::getTime() const
{
   return time;
}
```

This is in my main program:

```
Time t1, t2;
for (int i = 1; i < counter; ++i)
        {
            if (V1.at(i).getPrice() == highestPrice)
            {
                time2 = V1.at(i).getTime;
                if (time2 != time1)
                {
                    cout << time2;
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I compare time1 & time2? I'm trying to avoid printing duplicate values of time in my program. V1 is a vector loaded with data from Stock object.

Comment: What *is* `Time`? Have you tried [overloading the `==` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) (or the `!=` operator) for the class?

Comment: Time.h is a separate class where I initialize hours, minutes, etc.

Comment: `time2 = V1.at(i).getTime;` does it get compiled?

Comment: That was a typo :) 

i did `time2 = V1.at(i).getTime();` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first whether `==` or `!=` operator is overloaded for type `Time`. You must provide your own meaning to operators which you are gonna to use in your code for user-defined types else you will get compiler errors.

something like below,

```
class Time
{
public:
      bool operator==(Time const & t1) const
      {
         return this.hour == t1.hour && this.min==t1.min;

      }
private:
     int min;
     int hour;
};
```

Comment: Why not simply do `return hour == t1.hour && min == t1.min`? No need for the ternary expression.

Comment: @GautamNath Note that for the inequality operator `!=`, you don't need to implement the full logic, just use the equality operator combined with the logical not operator `!`, like `return !(*this == theOtherObject)`. For something simple like the above it doesn't really matter, but for object with more complicated comparison logic reusing the equality operator will make it simpler.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you are correct ... no need for ?: in above code

Comment: A const object cannot use `==` - find out why!

Comment: @Ajay I can't get what you mean to say? Did you mean that in above code we can't use `==` operator to compare current object and one that is passed by const-reference? I find no reason why this is illegal?

Comment: A `const` object cannot call a non-const function. The operator you implemented is a non-const, not a const. It should be const. Get it? :)

Comment: Well for now I did `friend bool operator == (const Time&, const Time&);` in the header file and `bool operator == (const Time& t1, const Time& t2)
{
 return (t1.hours == t2.hours && t1.minutes == t2.minutes);
}` in the cpp file. This seemed to work perfectly too.

Comment: Yes, because now the arguments (left, right side to `==` at call site) are const.

Comment: @Ajay I got it :) Corrected it!

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to answer your question completely, it would be necessary to know the details of the type "Time". Since you talk about comparing two objects, let's assume it is class.

If it was simple class like this:

```
class Time {
    public:
        int getValue();
        void setValue(int value);
    private:
        int value;
}
```

You would need to use getValue method:

```
if( t1.getValue() == t2.getValue())
```

If you want to compare the objects directly, you need to overload the necessary operators:

```
bool operator==(const Time& anotherTime) const {
    return (anotherTime.getValue()==this->getValue());
}
```

Comment: No need for the `if`, just doing `return getValue() == anotherTime.getValue()` will be enough.